# Is AC voltage across transformer pi shifted?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Suppose the voltage in the primary coil in a capacitor be

> V<sub>primary</sub> = V<sub>o</sub>sin(wt)

According to my understanding, as the (AC) current in the circuit increases, the Magnetic flux across the secondary coils increases. This induces an EMF that drives current in the secondary coil to nullify the increasing Magnetic flux. Hence a current in the opposite direction would flow.

Thus, I would conclude that AC current-waveforms for primary and secondary coils are Pi-Shifted. That is, there is a shift of half the wavelength for both currents.

Hence, I would also conclude that since Voltage would lead the current by the same angle $phi$, Voltages would be pi-shifted as well.

I reckon,

> V<sub>secondary</sub> = V<sub>o</sub>sin(wt + $pi$) * N1/N2

Is that correct? Or would there be no phase shifts?

Comment: It all depends on how the coils are wound relative to one another. This [article on the dot convention](https://circuitdigest.com/article/understanding-dot-convention-in-transformers) explains all.

Comment: The phase shift is dynamically determined by the load, the type of load, and so forth.